# Populating Backbone model with nested object

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a model called User which, when I do a Fetch, would ideally expect to receive a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{"UserId":"20","FirstName":"Test","SurName":"User"}
```

But the object that comes back, and that I need to work with, looks like this:

```json
{
    "Type": "Single",
    "Error: "",
    "Objects": {
        "UserId":"20",
        "FirstName":"Test",
        "SurName":"User"
    }
}
```

This is likely to be true for all of the models in my application.

What's the best way to tell the models to populate themselves from the `Objects` object rather than the root object?

Apologies if my question isn't as clear as it could be: I'm a Backbone virgin and this is all new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `parse` method of your model.

```
var FooModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(response) {
        //response is the raw JSON object. Whatever this method returns is used to populate the model.
        return response.Objects;
    }
});
```

See [Backbone documentation for Model.parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse).

Comment: Or override Backbone.Model.prototype.parse if it is needed for all models.

Comment: @nikoshr or define your own `ModelBase` (or similar) which overrides parse, and extend your models from that. Runtime monkey patching causes me to lose sleep.